# Swift iOS -How to test for only Return "\n" key character being entered inside a TextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, carriage-return, removing-whitespace

I have a textView that tests for white space using the delegates

```
fileprivate let whitespace = CharacterSet.whitespaces

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespace) == ""{
            sendButton.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            sendButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespace) == ""{
            sendButton.isEnabled = false
            sendButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        }else{
            sendButton.isEnabled = true
            sendButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        }
    }
```

If the user enters all spaces the the sendButton never becomes enabled. But if the user types in 1 or more return key characters "\n" it's still recognized as a character and the sendButton does become enabled.

In the textView delegates `shouldChangeTextInRange`, `textViewDidChange`, and `textViewDidEndEditing` I tried adding `textView.text! == "\n"`:

```
fileprivate let whitespace = CharacterSet.whitespaces

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespace) == "" || textView.text! == "\n"{
            sendButton.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            sendButton.isEnabled = true
        }    }

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespace) == "" || textView.text! == "\n"{
            sendButton.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            sendButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if textView.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespace) == "" || textView.text! == "\n"{
            sendButton.isEnabled = false
        }else{
            sendButton.isEnabled = true
        }
        return true
    }
```

The button still becomes enabled.

How do I get the same response as testing for whitespace only?

Comment: Change `Characterset.whitesspaces` to `.whitespacesAndNewlines`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks i'm trying it right now

Comment: @rmaddy I tried if textView.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: Characterset.whitesspacesAndNewLines) == "" in the delegate shouldChangeTextInRange and textViewDidChnage but it still becomes enabled

Comment: [Edit] your question with a little more context. Show the complete method containing this code.

Comment: @rmaddy i updated it

Comment: The enter button in a text view is actually an empty string. why won't you just check if the textview.text.isEmpty? something like 

sendButton.isEnabled = !textview.text.isEmpty

Comment: @user1883621 I believe I tried that but I don't remember what happened. I'll try again when I get home as maybe I did something wrong. Thanks

Comment: @rmaddy thanks! Your suggestion worked. I used it incorrectly

Comment: @user1883621 you were Correct! I remember what happened. At first I was using .isEmpty but whitespace was still being acknowledged. After I found out how to test for whitespace I said to myself what's the point of .isEmpty. Now that I think about as soon as I stopped using .isEmpty is when the "\n" started to get acknowledged. Any how thanks I upvoted your comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what you're doing here:

```
    if textView.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespace) == "" || textView.text! == "\n" {
```

Split that into pieces:

```
    // Part 1 - get the text from textView, and remove whitespace characters
    textView.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespace)

    // Part 2 - get the text from textView
    textView.text!

    IF "Part 1" == ""
    OR
    IF "Part 2" == "\n"
```

So, what happens if textView contains 4 spaces and a carriage return?

Part 1 is not true, because stripping the spaces leaves you with "\n"

Part 2 is not true, because it is "(four spaces)\n"

That should explain why your current code is not getting what you expect.

However, as @rmaddy suggested, this should do it:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let str = textView.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    if str == "" {
        sendButton.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        sendButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I left my house and I don;t have my cpu with me. When I get home I'll go over what you said and test it out. Much appreciated!

Comment: muchas gracias! it worked :) I understand your comments. I didn;t think about what if they enter with spaces and the return key. Good thinking